# Android Form Generator / Dynamic Interface Generator

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanted to generate a Dynamic Interface using the values stored in SQLLite I know how to generate it from a JSON I just wanted it to be generated from values in the sqllite .

Can any one help me please I have followed this link http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/04/android-form-generator/.

Comment: Take a look at using and extending SQLiteOpenHelper class, you can write SQL SELECT queries with it

Comment: i can only generate forms using JSON fomat.

Comment: Can you take the values from SQLite and assemble JSON from them?